# Too many connections with Spring + MyBatis + MySQL + JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, connection-pooling, mybatis

I am trying to work with spring, mybatis and mysql with jdbc. The only small problem I have after some queries, it throws an exception. The DB says: Too many connections.

So what I am trying to do to prevent the too many connection issue is to set up a connection pool. I have tried dbcp and bonecp also but both have the same behaviour. When I reload my page it just keeps loading in the browser and after some debugging it seems it hangs after the 9th or 10th select.

My scenario looks like this:

**1: "select * from maincategory"**

This query returns around 15 categories. I map the resultset into a List containing MainCategory elements.

Then what I do is I walk through the MainCategory List and get the IDs from each MainCategory and then I do an other select to get their sub categories:

**2: "select * from subcategories where id = ${id_from_main_category_actual_row}"**

And it seems it hangs after the 9th or 10th subcategory selection.

Here is my transaction manager and sqlsessionfactory configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="transactionManager"  
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">  
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
</beans:bean>  

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<beans:bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">  
    <beans:property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/spring/myBatis/mybatis.xml" />  
    <beans:property name="mapperLocations" value="WEB-INF/spring/myBatis/mbmapper-*.xml" />  
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
</beans:bean>
```

And here is the configuration for a datasource with dbcp:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource"  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value=""/>
</beans:bean>
```

And my other try was with the bonecp:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value=""/>
    <beans:property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInSeconds" value="30"/>
    <beans:property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="1"/>
    <beans:property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="7"/>
    <beans:property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="7"/>
    <beans:property name="partitionCount" value="1"/>
    <beans:property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
    <beans:property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="1"/>
    <beans:property name="acquireRetryDelayInMs" value="5000"/>
    <beans:property name="maxConnectionAgeInSeconds" value="0"/>
    <beans:property name="connectionTestStatement" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <beans:property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
    <beans:property name="disableConnectionTracking" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>
```

As you can see I tried many optimization on this with the properties. I think regardless if the method querying for main and their subcategories is a good or wrong practise, its only 10 small queries with some data returned so it should work.

If I use the "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" as the datasource, the db says the "too many connection" after some page refresh, while the tried connection pools just hang after the mentioned amount of query.

**UPDATE** based on comments:

Here is my detailed code as requested:

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/ApplicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/ApplicationContext-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>




    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**root-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

**ApplicationContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator" />

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
    <context:annotation-config />  

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <!-- 
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.packit" />

    <!-- Thymeleaf Template & View Resolver configurations -->
    <beans:bean id="templateResolver"
          class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
      <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
      <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
      <beans:property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
      <beans:property name="cacheable" value="false" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
      <beans:property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
      <beans:property name="additionalDialects">
             <beans:set>
                 <beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect" />
             </beans:set>
         </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
      <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </beans:bean> 

    <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="localization/general/messages" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
        <beans:property name="password" value=""/>
        <beans:property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInSeconds" value="30"/>
        <beans:property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="1"/>
        <beans:property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="7"/>
        <beans:property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="7"/>
        <beans:property name="partitionCount" value="1"/>
        <beans:property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
        <beans:property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="1"/>
        <beans:property name="acquireRetryDelayInMs" value="5000"/>
        <beans:property name="maxConnectionAgeInSeconds" value="0"/>
        <beans:property name="connectionTestStatement" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <beans:property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
        <beans:property name="disableConnectionTracking" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!--
    <beans:bean id="dataSource"  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
        <beans:property name="password" value=""/>
    </beans:bean>
    -->

    <!-- Original data source without connection pooling -->
    <!--
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />  
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />  
        <beans:property name="password" value="" />  
    </beans:bean> 
    -->

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"  
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">  
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
    </beans:bean>  

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <beans:bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">  
        <beans:property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/spring/myBatis/mybatis.xml" />  
        <beans:property name="mapperLocations" value="WEB-INF/spring/myBatis/mbmapper-*.xml" />  
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
    </beans:bean>  

    <!-- MAPPER: ACCOUNT -->
    <beans:bean id="accountDao" class="com.test.packit.dao.AccountDao">  
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />  
    </beans:bean>  
    <beans:bean id="accountService" class="com.test.packit.service.AccountService">  
        <beans:property name="accountDao" ref="accountDao" />  
    </beans:bean>  

    <!-- MAPPER: MAIN_CATEGORY -->
    <beans:bean id="mainCategoryDao" class="com.test.packit.dao.MainCategoryDao">  
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />  
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="mainCategoryService" class="com.test.packit.service.MainCategoryService">  
        <beans:property name="mainCategoryDao" ref="mainCategoryDao" />  
    </beans:bean>   


    <!-- MAPPER: SUB_CATEGORY -->
    <beans:bean id="subCategoryDao" class="com.test.packit.dao.SubCategoryDao">  
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />  
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="subCategoryService" class="com.test.packit.service.SubCategoryService">  
        <beans:property name="subCategoryDao" ref="subCategoryDao" />  
    </beans:bean>   
</beans:beans>
```

**ApplicationContext-security.xml:**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin.jsp" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />  
        <intercept-url pattern="/user.jsp" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <session-management session-fixation-protection="none">  
            <concurrency-control />  
        </session-management>  

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login"
            login-processing-url="/letmein"
            default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/login-error"
            username-parameter="bm_username"
            password-parameter="bm_password" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout"/>
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>

        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"  
                users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled  
                                        FROM bm_users  
                                        WHERE username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, role  
                                              FROM bm_roles  
                                              WHERE username=?" />  
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt"/>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>  
</beans:beans>
```

**mybatis.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">  
<configuration>  

</configuration>
```

**mbmapper-mainCategory-mapper.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"   
 "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">  

<mapper namespace="maincategory">
    <cache type="org.mybatis.caches.hazelcast.LoggingHazelcastCache"/>

    <select id="getAllMainCategories" resultType="list" resultMap="mainCategoryMap.mainCategoryResultMap">  
    SELECT * FROM packit.bm_maincategory;
    </select>
</mapper>
```

**mbmapper-mainCategory-resultMap.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">  

<mapper namespace="mainCategoryMap">  
    <resultMap type="com.test.packit.model.MainCategory" id="mainCategoryResultMap">  
       <id property="id" column="id"/>
       <result property="name" column="name"/>  
    </resultMap>  
</mapper>
```

**mbmapper-subCategory-mapper.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"   
 "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">  

<mapper namespace="subcategory">
    <cache type="org.mybatis.caches.hazelcast.LoggingHazelcastCache"/>

    <select id="getAllSubCategoriesForMainCategory" parameterType="int" resultType="list" resultMap="subCategoryMap.subCategoryResultMap">  
    SELECT * FROM packit.bm_subcategory WHERE maincategory_id = #{id};
    </select>
</mapper>
```

**mbmapper-subCategory-resultMap.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">  

<mapper namespace="subCategoryMap">  
    <resultMap type="com.test.packit.model.SubCategory" id="subCategoryResultMap">  
       <id property="id" column="id"/>
       <result property="name" column="name"/>  
    </resultMap>  
</mapper>
```

**MainCategory.java:**

```
package com.test.packit.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class MainCategory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7970848646314840509L;

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private List<SubCategory> subCategories;

    public List<SubCategory> getSubCategories() {
        return subCategories;
    }

    public void setSubCategories(List<SubCategory> subCategories) {
        this.subCategories = subCategories;
    }

    public MainCategory() {
        super();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**MainCategoryDao.java:**

```
package com.test.packit.dao;

import java.util.List;  

import javax.annotation.Resource;  

import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;  
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;  

import com.test.packit.model.MainCategory;

@Repository  
public class MainCategoryDao {  

    @Resource  
    private SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory;  

    public SqlSessionFactory getSessionFactory() {  
        return sessionFactory;  
    }  

    public void setSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory) {  
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;  
    }  

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
    public List<MainCategory> getAllMainCategories(){  
        SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<MainCategory> mainCategoriesFromDb = (List<MainCategory>)(List<?>) session.selectList("maincategory.getAllMainCategories");  
        return mainCategoriesFromDb;  

    }  

}
```

**MainCategoryService.java:**

```
package com.test.packit.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.test.packit.dao.MainCategoryDao;
import com.test.packit.model.MainCategory;

@Repository
public class MainCategoryService {
    @Resource
    private MainCategoryDao mainCategoryDao;

    public List<MainCategory> getAllCategories() {

        return mainCategoryDao.getAllMainCategories();
    }

    public MainCategoryDao getMainCategoryDao() {
        return mainCategoryDao;
    }

    public void setMainCategoryDao(MainCategoryDao mainCategoryDao) {
        this.mainCategoryDao = mainCategoryDao;
    }

}
```

**SubCategory.java:**

```
package com.test.packit.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class SubCategory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7970848646314840509L;

    private Integer id;
    private Integer mainCategoryId;
    private String name;

    public Integer getMainCategoryId() {
        return mainCategoryId;
    }

    public void setMainCategoryId(Integer mainCategoryId) {
        this.mainCategoryId = mainCategoryId;
    }

    public SubCategory() {
        super();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**SubCategoryDao.java:**

```
package com.test.packit.dao;

import java.util.List;  

import javax.annotation.Resource;  

import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;  
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;  

import com.test.packit.model.SubCategory;

@Repository  
public class SubCategoryDao {  

    @Resource  
    private SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory;  

    public SqlSessionFactory getSessionFactory() {  
        return sessionFactory;  
    }  

    public void setSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory) {  
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;  
    }  

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
    public List<SubCategory> getAllSubCategoriesForMainCategory(int id){  
        SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<SubCategory> subCategoriesFromDb = (List<SubCategory>)(List<?>) session.selectList("subcategory.getAllSubCategoriesForMainCategory", id);  
        return subCategoriesFromDb;  

    }  

}
```

**SubCategoryService.java:**

```
package com.test.packit.dao;

import java.util.List;  

import javax.annotation.Resource;  

import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;  
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;  

import com.test.packit.model.SubCategory;

@Repository  
public class SubCategoryDao {  

    @Resource  
    private SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory;  

    public SqlSessionFactory getSessionFactory() {  
        return sessionFactory;  
    }  

    public void setSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory) {  
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;  
    }  

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
    public List<SubCategory> getAllSubCategoriesForMainCategory(int id){  
        SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<SubCategory> subCategoriesFromDb = (List<SubCategory>)(List<?>) session.selectList("subcategory.getAllSubCategoriesForMainCategory", id);  
        return subCategoriesFromDb;  

    }  

}
```

**HomeController.java:**

```
package com.test.packit;

import com.test.packit.authentication.AuthenticatorController;
import com.test.packit.model.MainCategory;
import com.test.packit.model.SubCategory;
import com.test.packit.service.MainCategoryService;
import com.test.packit.service.SubCategoryService;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

     @Resource
     private MainCategoryService mainCategoryService;
     private List<MainCategory> mainCategories;

     @Resource
     private SubCategoryService subCategoryService;
     private List<SubCategory> subCategories;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Locale locale, Model model) {

        // Get all main categories
        mainCategories = mainCategoryService.getAllCategories();
        for(MainCategory mainCategory : mainCategories) {
            logger.info("Main Category: {}", mainCategory.getName());

            // Get all sub categories
            subCategories = subCategoryService.getAllSubCategoriesForMainCategory(mainCategory.getId());
            mainCategory.setSubCategories(subCategories);
            for(SubCategory subCategory : subCategories) {
                logger.info("\t\t- {}", subCategory.getName());
            }
        }
        model.addAttribute("mainCategories", mainCategories);

        return "index";
    }

}
```

Any suggestion are very welcomed.

Comment: We need to see the Java - it sounds like a session management problem.

Comment: In general that means wrong setup of your transaction management. Also I would strongly suggest rewriting your strategy to include all in a single query. You now have the problem of the [1+N select problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue).

Comment: Have you tried with other database connection pool libraries?

Comment: kiwiron: I updated the thread with all of my xmls and codes. M. Deinum: thanks for the suggestion. I will rewrite the queries once it is solved. Ian Lim: no, just only these two, dbcp and bonecp. I hope somehow we can figure out something on this problem. Many thanks.

Comment: From the [MyBatis documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html#sqlSessions): "The most important thing you must ensure is that you close any sessions that you open." Looking at `SubCategoryDao.java` and `SubCategoryService.java` this is not happening ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. When creating SqlSessions manually you have to make sure that you close them after use.

Look for all places where you are opening a SqlSession:

```
SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Make sure that you're closing the session after use. You should do that in try-finally block, like below:

```
SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(); 
try {
    // following 3 lines pseudocode for "doing some work"
    session.insert(...);
    session.update(...);
    session.delete(...);
    session.commit();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

More information on how to handle MyBatis SqlSessions can be found here: http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html#sqlSessions

### 2. You can use MyBatis-Spring to create and manage the lifecycle of SqlSessions.

Instead of injecting DAO's with SqlSessionFactory, you can ask spring to inject the SqlSessions directly. When you do this, Spring will manage the SqlSessions for you, so you will not have to open/close sessions by yourself.
More information how to do this is here: http://mybatis.github.io/spring/sqlsession.html